# aptitude produces output twice

Tags: aptitude, stdout, stderr

For quite a while, I get a double output of some messages from aptitude.
Here’s an example:

```
> sudo aptitude install mpw
Couldn't find package "mpw".  However, the following
packages contain "mpw" in their name:
  stumpwm 
Couldn't find package "mpw".  However, the following
packages contain "mpw" in their name:
  stumpwm 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1019 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Still, this doesn’t happen with every message:

```
> sudo aptitude install mpv
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1019 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

This is my aptitude version:

```
> aptitude --version
aptitude 0.6.8.2 compiled at Nov  5 2012 06:20:41
Compiler: g++ 4.7.2
Compiled against:
  apt version 4.12.0
  NCurses version 5.9
  libsigc++ version: 2.2.10
  Ept support enabled.
  Gtk+ support disabled.
  Qt support disabled.

Current library versions:
  NCurses version: ncurses 5.9.20130608
  cwidget version: 0.5.16
  Apt version: 4.12.0
```

How can I fix that?

I almost forgot: I noticed that the doubled messages are exactly errors as far as I can tell. So maybe this has to do with stderr?

This is on a debian testing/unstable.

Comment: What os and release?

Comment: @FaheemMitha See my edit: debian testing/unstable

Comment: I can reproduce this on stable. Looks like a bug. I suggest you check and see if it is already listed, and if not, file it.

Comment: Might be http://bugs.debian.org/498239

Comment: @FaheemMitha Oh, okay. Well then I’ll just wait for it to get fixed. Thanks.

Comment: You might have a long wait. This bug is already 5 years old, and aptitude does not exactly have an active development team. I suppose you know Daniel Burrows, the original aptitude developer, is no longer active. It would do no harm to post to the report asking about current status. If you know C++ you could poke around and see if you can figure out why the repeat is happening. It is possible the fix is not difficult.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Well, it’s a minor thing – wouldn’t I bother the developers by bumping the bug report?

Comment: No, I think it is harmless. I've actually bought long forgotten bugs to the attention of developers that way. Of course, as you say, it is relatively minor, so they may not care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like [Debian bug 498239: warnings, status printed twice](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=498239), filed 8th September 2008.

Amusing curiosity: the same user reported the same bug four times. :-)